# open source signal processing libraries

Tags: audio

Are there any open source libraries/projects which work in a similar way to http://www.tagattitude.fr/en/products/technology?

I am trying to understand the process. At first I thought this could work like when you send a fax to a fax machine.

It is basically using the mobile phone’s microphone as a captor and its audio channel as a transporter.

Are there any libraries for generating the signal and then being able to decode it?

Comment: Preprocessor tag means C/C++ preprocessor.

Answer (score 0):

- Take a look at this library [saajoby](http://saajoby.sourceforge.net/).
- And [here](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/9340/how-could-you-transfer-data-over-an-audio)
- And [here](http://awesomegeekblog.blogspot.gr/2009/04/file-transfer-over-sound-card.html)